# Trying to retrieve Favicons from a URL

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to retrieve favicons from random URL's in a feed that are called up from a ~~~Link~~~ Variable.

> (I.E. Upon page load ~~~link~~~ =
>   https://www.website.com/2018/09/30/world/etc...
>   Retrieve favicon,
>   and display favicon as a img in html.

What would be an easy way to go about this? Ive tried a few methods but have had no success so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You are supposed to show us what you have tried, and ask specific questions about what problems you are having with it. _“Ive tried a few methods but have had no success”_ is not a proper basis for a question here on SO.

Comment: I found an answer but thank you i will keep this in mind for future questions. I definitely could of included some more info.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my 30 of so minutes of waiting i discovered that google offers a really easy solution for this problem.

The Solution? This "one liner" offered by google: https://plus.google.com/_/favicon?domain=~~~ItemLink~~~

^ This one line does everything needed. For anyone that might want to implement this just replace ~~~ItemLink~~~ with the URL you wish to retrieve the favicon for.

You can simply insert that link into the src attribute of your img tag and it will display the favicon of the url.

Example: [https://plus.google.com/*/favicon?domain=www.stackoverflow.com*](https://plus.google.com/_/favicon?domain=www.stackoverflow.com)
Or: [https://plus.google.com//favicon?domain=http://www.website.com](https://plus.google.com/_/favicon?domain=http://www.website.com)

^ That will pull the favicon from any domain. To get the favicon for an URL, use:
https://plus.google.com/_/favicon?domain_url=http://www.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

First off, why are you parsing the favicon through a URL string?

Anyhow, you will need to do `www.some_page.php?favicon=some_string_path`. Then in your some_page.php, you will need to retrieve the image path like `$favicon=$_GET['favicon']`.

You then put that into the image source.

`<img src="<?php echo $favicon; ?>">`

Explanation:

When you parse something through a URL string it's called a `GET` method. The way it works is that at the end of the page url, you add a `?` then the variable name, then `=` and what the variable should contain. You then fetch the get variable via PHP `$_GET`.

You can parse multiple variables in the URL by adding a `&` at the end of each variable.

Example `some_page.php?varOne=1&varTwo=2`.

Comment: That would of worked nicely, but I think I found a easier solution. I'm just going to have google do all the hard lifting. I posted my solution that i found below, as an answer. Thank you for your contribution though!